# Flutter build split doesn't creating x86 apk?

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter doesn't create x86 apk but the other three apk's created.

Recently released Android application firebase crashes heads up with **x86 couldn't find "libflutter.so"**. So I thought we have released a bundled app in that x86 lib folder or lib releated may not created so crash happened. And I tried to create a split apk in the local machine using `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` its created three files **"arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64"** but **x86 apk not created** I have no idea or any configuration I missed to do it?

Help me out. Thanks in advance!

```
maclap@root flutter-app-v3 % flutter build apk --split-per-abi

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 1109KB to 1052KB: Removed 5%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 1109KB to 1052KB: Removed 5%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 1109KB to 1052KB: Removed 5%
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           68.0s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (18.1MB).
```

In, android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    ndk {
        abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Flutter does not currently support building for x86 Android. more details -> https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android   
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253

Answer (score 6):

`flutter build apk --split-per-abi` only generate three apk files [source](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-apk)

```
1 - app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (ARM 32-bit)
2 - app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (ARM 64-bit)
3 - app-x86_64-release.apk (x86 64-bit)
```

**Flutter does not currently support building for x86 Android** [Source](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures)

**Solution:** You can run `flutter build apk` command to generate `app-release.apk` [fat](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-is-a-fat-apk) APK that is single APK runs on multiple architectures

Comment: Yes It's working make sure old emulator APK uninstall first if it's there already.